# What if Active NameNode fails when SbNN operations are blocked?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

In hadoop 2 hdfs architecture, StandBy Name Node was introduced. It will also do the job of Secondary NameNode of hadoop 1. i.e. creating fs image from edit logs. When it is in this process of creating fsimage, most of SbNN's operations are blocked as mentioned in the blog link provided.
    (http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/03/a-guide-to-checkpointing-in-hadoop/)

What if the Active Name Node fails at this time?
Does SbNN will be taking some time to take its place?

Answer (score 0):

In High-availability mode,you should not start secondary/checpoint node, as that will result in error in case of activenode fails.
Since standby namenode is doing all their duties already

Comment: if any query ask me ?